# System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for 'SQLite.SQLiteConnection' threw an exception.'

Tags: c#, sql, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

When i add the **Sql-net-pcl** library in my xamarin app, and compile, then it showing me an exception and saying that your application is in break mode.

**Exception :**

```
     `System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for 'SQLite.SQLiteConnection' threw an exception.'
```

**ISqLiteDb :**

```
public interface ISqLiteDb
{
    SQLiteAsyncConnection GetConnection();
}
```

**SqLiteDb :**

```
class SqLiteDb: ISqLiteDb
{
    public SQLiteAsyncConnection GetConnection()
    {
        var documePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
        var path = Path.Combine(documePath, "Shopping.db");

        return new SQLiteAsyncConnection(path);
    }
}
```

And here i am opening the connection and creating the table.

**MainPage.Xaml.cs :**

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    private ObservableCollection<Recipe> _recipes;

    private readonly SQLiteAsyncConnection _connection;
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _connection = DependencyService.Get<ISqLiteDb>().GetConnection();
    }

    protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        await _connection.CreateTableAsync<Recipe>();
        var recipes = await _connection.Table<Recipe>().ToListAsync();

        _recipes = new ObservableCollection<Recipe>(recipes);

        listView.ItemsSource = _recipes;
    }

    private async void OnAdd(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var recipe = new Recipe
        {
            Id = 1,
            Name = "Recipe1"
        };

        await _connection.InsertAsync(recipe);
        _recipes.Add(recipe);
    }
```

Comment: I guess your `documePath` variable is null either or empty. Make sure it has filled as expected.

Comment: This is compile time? It would be helpful to get more details. There might be some in the "build" output window.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, i have checked the documentPath, documenPath variable is not empty neither null

Comment: I guess if you delete the "bin" and "obj" folders , solve it. also Make sure you have installed the latest stable version of the  "sqlite-net-pcl" .

Comment: I have already try this techinque but again show ing me same exception.